# Sorry, this product cannot be purchased. Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a advance custom field using ACF wordpress plugin to check if the product is available for this month or not. The code I am using is below but when it does work to point where it shows add to cart button if the product is available for that month if not then shows the message.

Now the issue is when product is available to purchase if I click on add to cart it says "Sorry, this product cannot be purchased." I am not able to find what is wrong with it.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback( $purchasable, $product ) {
    $months      = (array) get_field('availability');
    $purchasable = in_array( date('F'), $months ) ? $purchasable : false;

    return $purchasable;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'unavailable_product_display_message', 20 );
function unavailable_product_display_message() {
    global $product;

    if(! $product->is_purchasable() ){
        echo '<p style="color:#e00000;">' . __("This product is currently unavailable.") . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this line of code:

```
$months = (array) get_field('availability');
```

to:

```
$months = (array) get_field('availability', $product->get_id());
```

The get_field function doesn`t know from which product to get, so this will be an empty array. The variable $purchasable will always be false when this happens.